# How associated products attribute display on product page (Grouped product)

Tags: magento-1.9, product

I need to show my associated products custom attribute like size,color under Grouped product. Inside the below table code. I am a beginner in magento project. Please give a solution.

[image]

```
<?php foreach ($_associatedProducts as $_item): ?>
    <?php $_finalPriceInclTax = $this->helper('tax')->getPrice($_item, $_item->getFinalPrice(), true) ?>
    <tr>
        <td><!--Color--></td>
        <td><!--Size--></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the below code which solved my problem.

```
    <td><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getAttributeText('shirtcolor'));  ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getAttributeText('shirtsize'));  ?></td>
```

If anybody tried solution for my question Thank You!